# Determine the next image in the sequence

Tags: pattern

This is a standardized test practice question asking for the next image in the sequence. Can anyone identify the pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here are two different methods that give the same solution which is:

> **answer a**

Based on sequential logic:

> From the **gray diamonds**, the fifth image could also be a combination of image one and three (as the fourth image could be a combination of image one and two).
>
>   The sequence for the **arrow** is up, down, left, right.  If repeating, next should be up.
>
>   The **color of the dots** could be 0=white, 1=gray, 2=black (a base 3 system).  So adding the dots for image one and two gives white-gray-black-gray which is the pattern for image 4 (starting at top left and going clockwise).  It follows that the dots for image 5 should be white-gray-black-white.
>
>   The **keyhole at the edge** has a sequence of left, top, right, top.  If repeating, the next should be left.
>
>   The **square around the dot** has a sequence of none, top left, none, bottom left.  If repeating, the next should be none.
>
>   Putting this together fits the pattern for **answer a**.

Based on incorrect answers being formulated in regions surrounding the correct answer:

> The **most common elements** in the five answers are arrow=up, dot colors=white-gray-black-white, keyhole=left, square around dot = none.
>
>  These most common elements coincide with **answer a**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Option A

I've chosen this option because

> I've noticed that when there are two grey circles in the big square, then the grey circle opposite to the direction that the arrow points to has a small square around it.

Also

> I am assuming that there will not be more than one black circle in the big square as there is just one in each image.

Moreover,

> The arrows in each image point at directions up,down,left and right and the "door" at left,up,right,up. So, the next arrow will probably point up and the "door" at left.

So, by elimination, I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By eliminating,I think the answer is

> A

Clue 1

> The four dots in upper big square,must be 2 white,1 grey,1 black.The 2nd and 4th are not,but one grey dot is in a square.So I guess square turns a white dot to grey(or turns grey to black).
>
>   Looking at the choices,with the same rule,C and D fails,they have 2 grey dots without square surrounding,E fails too,it has square,but imagine it without square,it includes 2 grey dots too. The rest are A or B

Except for clue 1,I don't really have confidence to know which and why that is the answer,but here's what information I get at least.

Rest of Clues

> Clue 2. As clue 1 said, the answer is either A or B,they have two same dots,white and black down there.So we have these two dots to find the pattern.
>
>   Clue 3. the three diamond below should be independent,they affects how the pattern above to be formed.That's why it gives us the 3 diamonds for the 5th one.
>
>   Clue 4. In clock wise,the dot next to the arrow is usually grey,except for the 4th one.Considering this,A would be the answer.
>
>   Clue 5. If A is the answer,comparing it with the 1st,they are similar,share the same arrow and mini-square.But here's what stops me,I can't go further.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the solution you are looking for, but with finding similarities in options and elimination I choose...

> **C**

Explanation:

4 of options has arrow up. **b** is eliminated

None of four leads (upper images) has two black circles. **e** is eliminated

Locations of gray, white and black circle in *c* and *d* is exactly the same. **a** is eliminated

Finally, between *c* and *d*, I choose *c* because it is more similar to the last eliminated option (*a*) than *d*.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it's A.
I simply realised that the big squares were only present in alternate boxes i.e, there was no big square on the first box , it was present in the second box and so on.Thus I cancelled out B and E since the answer should not have the big square.Then I saw that there was two white circles in the first box,only one in the second box , two again in the third box and so on. With this I managed to cancel out C and D as the answer required two white circles. This left me with the answer A.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is A by elimination. So this is the pattern I see.  A square containing (2 white, 1 black and 1 grey circle) is always followed by a square containing(2grey, 1black and 1 white circle). The vice versa is also true.

Based on this we go through the options for a square containing (2 white, 1 black and 1 grey circle) since that pattern is what comes after a square containing (2grey, 1black and 1 white circle).

Option A is the only one with that and hence I choose that. Supposing we had more than 1, I will consider the arrow direction in each square next

Comment: Welcome to [Puzzling.SE]! Is your answer really different from the other seven ones? If so, please consider using spoiler markup (`>!`) to hide your solution, like the other answers do.